# Android: Google Maps V2 only as a fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I would like to show a Google Maps as one of my 3 pages in a ViewPager.

I was thinking to use Views instead of Fragments inside my ViewPager, but I have only found examples with Google Maps V2 being a fragment. So, I guess I will have to make each ViewPager page a fragment.

Can you confirm that Google Maps V2 can only be a fragment?

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking to use Views instead of Fragments inside my ViewPager

`ViewPager` most commonly uses `Fragments` via `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`. By using `Fragments` you can supply and manage the lifecycle of each page.

> Can you confirm that Google Maps V2 can only be a fragment?

This is not necessarily the case. You can use a `MapView`.

Comment: I am currently using minSdk=14 and not importing the support library. Can you confirm me that if I decide to use `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager` I need to use the support library, as `getChildFragmentManager()` is only defined in API 17 ?

Comment: You do not need to use `getChildFragmentManager()`. That method is used to get references from a `Fragment` that is inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: Considering the `ViewPager` is inside a `Fragment`, don't I need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` to manage the `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Why would `ViewPager` be inside a `Fragment`? Think of a `ViewPager` like you would of any other `ViewGroup` (it is in fact a `ViewGroup`)

Comment: I am using a Master/Detail fragments architecture. In the master fragment I have the list, in the detail fragment I show the info of the clicked item using a view pager with 3 pages. So, yes, the `ViewPager` is inside a fragment (the detail fragment).

Comment: Then yes, you need to use the support library